# How to check if the checkbox is checked or not in php?

Tags: php

i have an if statement as follows
        if($_POST['remember']=="on")

i want to know if this is the correct syntax for checking if the checkbox is checked or unchecked?

Comment: use `isset($_POST['remember'])`

Comment: It would have been *faster* to answer this yourself with a basic test.

Answer (score 2):

This code will help you

```
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbx" <?php if(isset($_POST['remember'])=="on")  echo "checked";?> />
```

OR

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['remember'])=="on") {?>
 <input type="checkbox" name="checkbx" checked="checked"  />
<?php }else {?>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbx"  />
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

simple check of `isset`

```
if(isset($_POST['remember']) && $_POST['remember']=="on")
{
   // checkbox remember is checked
}
else
{
   // checkbox remember is not checked
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
if (isset($_POST['remember'])) {
     // checked
} else {
   not checked 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="remember" value="YES" />

$remember= ($_POST['remember'] == 'YES')?'YES':'NO';
```